# Python If statement on dataframe

Tags: python, if-statement, numpy, pandas

I would like to replace column df['pred'] with 0 if the respective value of df['nonzero'] is not 'NAN' and "<= 1".

```
         beta0  beta1  number_repair   t  pred  nonzero  
0          NaN    NaN            NaN   6     0      NaN  
1          NaN    NaN            NaN   7     0      NaN  
2          NaN    NaN            NaN   8     0      NaN  
3          NaN    NaN            NaN   9     3      0  
4          NaN    NaN            NaN  10     2      0  
5          NaN    NaN            NaN  11     1      0
```

I tried the following code but it returned error. How could I correct the code or could someone suggest other way to achieve it? Thanks!

```
mapping['pred'] = 0 if (np.all(np.isnan(mapping['nonzero'])),
(mapping['nonzero'] <= 1)) else mapping['pred']
```

Comment: Do you need to use a ternary? Have you tried just looping over the rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with `mask` by function [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html):

```
mask = (df['nonzero'].notnull()) & (df['nonzero'] <= 1)
print mask
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
Name: nonzero, dtype: bool
```

By [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36719191/python-if-statement-on-dataframe#comment61025203_36719295) (Thank you PhilChang) it is same as:

```
mask = df['nonzero'] <= 1
print mask
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
Name: nonzero, dtype: bool
```

```
df.loc[ mask, 'pred'] = 0
print df
   beta0  beta1  number_repair   t  pred  nonzero
0    NaN    NaN            NaN   6     0      NaN
1    NaN    NaN            NaN   7     0      NaN
2    NaN    NaN            NaN   8     0      NaN
3    NaN    NaN            NaN   9     0      0.0
4    NaN    NaN            NaN  10     0      0.0
5    NaN    NaN            NaN  11     0      0.0
```

Another solution with [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['pred'] = df.pred.mask(mask,0)
print df
   beta0  beta1  number_repair   t  pred  nonzero
0    NaN    NaN            NaN   6     0      NaN
1    NaN    NaN            NaN   7     0      NaN
2    NaN    NaN            NaN   8     0      NaN
3    NaN    NaN            NaN   9     0      0.0
4    NaN    NaN            NaN  10     0      0.0
5    NaN    NaN            NaN  11     0      0.0
```

Comment: In fact, notnull() is not necessary in this case. float number compared with nan is always false

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to check on a Series if cells contain 'NaN', but for the other condition, this works quite well:

```
df.ix[df.ix[:,'nonzero'] <=1,'pred'] = 0
```

You then just have to add after the first test "and my_second_test".